# implementation of vtk boxwidget2

Tags: python, vtk

Currently, I am trying to write a script to select the visualized points with user interaction. I looked through vtk sources and it seems one can use  widget called vtkBoxWidget2 to select. However, I can not find an example in python.
My aim is to let user resize and modify the boxwidget (that's easy with the pipeline ) and then select the points inside of the box and return the selected point ids
I would appreciate if anyone could share a snippet of the codes for this task in python.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what about [this](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/73001/vtk.vtkBoxWidget2)?

Comment: sorry but website at that address is down, I can't open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example where the usage of `vtkBoxWidget2` is demonstrated. It is located in the VTK source directory:

`interaction/Widgets/Testing/Python/TestInteractorEventRecorder.py`

Or just grab it from the [VTK repository on github](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Widgets/Testing/Python/TestInteractorEventRecorder.py).